# Between OAuth and OpenID, do I need to preserve the tokens?

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, openid

I'm creating a site that allows users to register/link Facebook/Twitter/Google etc to their accounts.

When authorizing via OpenID and OAuth/OAuth2, what tokens do I need to preserve so that I can make sure the app can update their Facebook status / Twitter wall?

Answer (score 0):

Well all you need to take care of preserving the `access_token` in all cases.This token is basically last part of any handshaking mechanism and with the help of this you will able to communicate with the Open-ID/OAuth party.